# BDD in Julia language

Tags: rspec, cucumber, bdd, hpc, julia

I would like to know if there is some tool to do BDD in **Julia language**, like **Rspec** or **Cucumber** in **Ruby**? I trying to find some tool similar, but I cannot find something like that, maybe because the language is too recent or BDD is not too popular in HPC "world".

I know that even in the "out-of-date" Fortran, there are some softwares to do TDD or BDD, so in Julia should have something in this sense, I just did not find yet.

Anyone know something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two test suites that I am aware of: Base.Test and FactCheck. It should be possible to use these for TDD, but I haven't tried. FactCheck might be appropriate for BDD, but I'm not sure.